# Not able to resume current page in my Windows Phone app using Cordova

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on a AngularJS project. I am running it on a Windows Phone using Cordova. When I minimize my app and click the app icon again in home screen, the app is restarting and opening again from home page. How am I able to resume my current page in the app using Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

@Abraham,
I do NOT runs windows, nor do I have windows phone. However under Android and iOS you need to extend the config.xml to the native configuration. I DO NOT KNOW if you can do this under windows.

With *Phonegap Build* you would extend the configuration via [Config File Elements](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements) and *gap:config-file* With Android you would set [android:alwaysRetainTaskState](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always). On iOS you would do similar. However, in the documentation I DO NOT see windows, but I have to image there is a method. I would go to the [Phonegap Build forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). They have people from phonegap that monitor that.